# Solving linear equations in five variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Is it possible to solve following 3 linear equations for 5 variables.

$$3.5\alpha_1+4\alpha_2+4.5\alpha_3-2\alpha_4-2.5\alpha_5=0.83$$
$$4.25\alpha_1+3\alpha_2+1.75\alpha_3-2\alpha_4-0.75\alpha_5=0.33$$
$$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=\alpha_4+\alpha_5$$
also.
$$\alpha_i>0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming $a,b,c,d,e$ the $\alpha_i$'s of the equations, you can consider two of them as constants (say $a$ and $b$) and solve for the other three.

This would give (hoping no mistake) $$c=-a-b+\frac{481}{1200}\qquad d=2 a+b+\frac{17}{300}\qquad e=-2 a-b+\frac{413}{1200}$$ Now, the last condition about the positivity gives $$c>0 \implies a+b <\frac{481}{1200}$$ $$e>0 \implies 2a+b <\frac{413}{1200}$$ Does these define a domain for $a,b$ ?

Comment: yes they do define the correct domain for a and b